# How to store a Google Drive FileList object for later use?

Tags: java, android, serialization, google-drive-api

How can I store a google **FileList** object in my Java/Android application? I've thought of using singleton, extending application class, service and so on to store this, but I'm not sure if I should do this. I tried to use Android's **Bundle** as well, but the **FileList** doesn't implement serializible or parcelable and it is marked as final.

I'm trying to achieve this because of device orientation changes, but so far I've had no success. I also need to pass this object between Activities so a retained fragment wouldn't function in the end.

What options do I have then? I really could use help as I've been stuck with this problem for a long time now.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why don't you try for making it static/global variable?

Comment: I think its a bad practice.

Comment: Ya its just a workaround for your problem

Answer (score 1):

GSON? Given the FileList got into your app over http/json, it shouldn't be too hard to serialize it back to a json string. There is probably a method buried in the google api stack that does it, but I would personally try GSON first as it's more stable.

Comment: I tried to use GSON for serializing as the object, but I had problems re-creating it. Something along the lines of, expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT. 

I tried it like this;
FileList fl = new GSON().fromJson(savedStringObject, FileList.class)

Comment: That sounds like a fairly simple problem to fix. I suggest you open a new question on SO, including the definition of the FileList class and the generated json.